# GitHub Desktop publish to 3rd party hosting

Tags: github

I'm very new in git, I have download GitHub Desktop to support me do all the commands.

GitHub Desktop its pretty friendly to use.

My question is

GitHub Desktop can only published to GitHub, is any way to publish to my own 3rd party hosting (i'm using hostgator)

Comment: I'm not sure about the GUI client, but you still have the shell and there you can set the remotes manually ([git remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) `add origin URL`) which if the GUI client respects (I *think* it does if you name it `origin`), it'll push to the remote.

Comment: You can add any repository to GitHub Desktop, whether it is on Github or now. [See docs here.](https://help.github.com/desktop/faq/articles/do-you-support-hosts-other-than-github/)

Comment: i know i can add repo to GitHub Desktop, but I want to push it to my hostgator hosting

Comment: @BenjaminW Yes, you can add Hostgator Git. Are you actually asking how to set up git on Hostgator? Just create the repo and add it.

Comment: im asking how to use GitHub Desktop public or push to hostgator server repo